# Complexity of the maximal minimum size problem

Tags: complexity-theory

Here is a question that I do not understand:

> There is a list of items $E = e_1,\dots,e_m$. Suppose we have two players (the first and second).
>
> Each item $e_j$ has a value $v(e_j) \ge 0$. The values are not necessarily integers.
>
> The value of a set of items $A \subseteq E$ is $v(A) = \sum_{e_j \in A} v(e_j)$.
>
> Let's look at the MMS problem in two players. Our goal is to partition the items between the two players.
>
> Let $P_{i,1},P_{i_2}$ be an enumeration of all partitions. Let $Z_i = \min(v(P_{i,1}),v(P_{i,2})$. The *minimum-maximum value* or *maximal minimum size* is $\max_i Z_i$.

For example, suppose that there are four items $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ whose values are
$$ v(e_1) = 3, v(e_2) = 5, v(e_3) = 4, v(e_4) = 2. $$
The possible partitions (stated in terms of values) are:

- $\emptyset, \{2,3,4,5\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 0.
- $\{2\}, \{3,4,5\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 2.
- $\{3\}, \{2,4,5\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 3.
- $\{4\}, \{2,3,5\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 4.
- $\{5\}, \{2,3,4\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 5.
- $\{2,3\}, \{4,5\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 5.
- $\{2,4\}, \{3,5\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 6.
- $\{2,5\}, \{3,4\}$ – the minimum value of a set is 7.

As you can see, the to parts are not ordered, so this is an exhaustive list of the possible partitions. The minimum-maximum value is 7, attained by the partition $\{2,5\},\{3,4\}$.

> In the decision problem MMS we are given a list of items $E$ together with their value function $v$ and a non-negative number $z$, and the problem is to decide whether the maximum minimum size is equal to $z$.

> Question 1: To which complexity class does MMS belong?
>
> 1. MMS belongs to P
> 2. MMS belongs to NP
> 3. MMS belongs to coNP
> 4. It is not known whether MMS belongs to coNP

> Question 2: What is an appropriate witness or algorithm for the answer in question 1?
>
> 1. There is a polynomial time algorithm which partitions the items greedily.
> 2. There is an efficient algorithm that verifies negative instances. The witness is a partition $P_1,P_2$ such that $\min(v(P_1),v(P_2)) > z$.
> 3. The witness is a partition $P_1,P_2$. If $z < \min(v(P_1),v(P_2))$, then we know that the answer is negative. But when $z > \min(v(P_1),v(P_2))$, we cannot conclude that the answer is negative.

I do not understand these two questions.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, they should be split up into multiple posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1.
The decision version of MMS is NP-hard by a reduction from partition but
it is currently unknown whether it belongs to $\mathsf{P}$, $\mathsf{NP}$, or $\mathsf{CO\!-\!NP}$.

Regarding question 2.

1. We don't know whether there exists a polynomial-time algorithm for MMS. I'm not aware of an argument that allows to rule out greedy algorithms (how would the class of greedy algorithms be formally defined in the first place?).
2. We don't know if there an efficient algorithm that verifies instances given that certificate. For example, if the problem is in $\mathsf{P}$, then the answer is trivially yes (regardless of the certificate).
3. This is correct, as far as we know. Notice that if MMS were in $\mathsf{P}$ then we would be able to conclude that the answer to a "no" instance is negative regardless of the certificate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, regarding the first question, because the partition problem is NPH and from it it is possible to make a reduction to MMS, so MMS is also NPH? If MMS is in NPH does not that mean it is also in NP and P?

Regarding the second question, why do we not actually have an efficient algorithm? If I have a witness who gives 2 groups, it is possible to count the sum of the groups, select the small group, and check if it is equal to z, is this not true?

Comment: @dustyeav Yes, MMS is NP-hard because you can give a *polytime* reduction from Partition to it. And no, being NP-hard does not imply the problem is also in NP or in P.

Comment: Yes, MMS is NP-Hard because there is a Karp reduction from Partition to MMS. The fact that MMS is NP-Hard doesn't imply that MMS is in NP nor that it is in P, although this might be the case. Regarding the second question: I can't possibly tell you **why** we don't have an efficient algorithm since it might be the case that such an algorithm exists, we just don't know one... If you have a witness that gives you two groups you can certainly do what you suggest however this doesn't result in an algorithm that verifies yes instances nor no instances.

Comment: Thanks, why according to the second question, when Z is less than the maximum minimum, we return false, and when Z is greater than the maximum minimum, why can we not return false as well? I do not understand what the difference is between these 2 cases.

Comment: Let $s$ be the minimum sum of the elements in one of the two groups of the certificate.  Even if $s=z$, you can't rule out the existence of another partition for which the minimum sum of the elements is larger than $z$. Hence this certificate doesn't allow you to conclude that you're dealing with a "yes" instance.
On the other hand, if $s<z$ there might be another partition for which the minimum sum of the elements is exactly $z$. So you can't use this a "no" certificate either.
If $s>z$ you can return false since the optimal value must be at least $s$ but $s$ already exceeds $z$.

Comment: Why if there is s = z it is not good? Why should other partitions be examined as well?

Comment: Even if $s=z$ for the certificate partition $(A,B)$, this only tells you that there is **some** partition with minimum value $z$. However the problem asks you to check whether the **maximum** among all the minimum values associated to **all possible partitions** is $z$. Let's call this maximum $m$. Clearly $m\ge s$. You could be in $2$ scenarios. Either the maximum is actually attained with the partition $(A,B)$, i.e., $m=s$ and the answer is "yes". Or the maximum is larger than $s$, i.e., $m > s = z$ and the answer is "no". How do  you efficiently decide in which of these two cases you're in?

Comment: Thanks, I can 't figure it out. Why when z is greater than s, false cannot be returned. If the witness gives us one case where z is greater than s, it means it is not equal to s, and because it is not equal to s, there is one case that it no longer works, so no need to check all the other partitions, because it sure will not work for everyone, Because already on one it does not work.

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you to check whether the equality holds **for all the partitions** but just for the **maximum among all the partitions**. The maximum might be larger than the value of the partition you are given in the certificate. I'm sorry, I don't know how to explain it better than I already did.